# How to close the spark connection in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, sparklyr

Whenever I open RStudio, I see `Spark` panel in the right top of `RStudio` as shown in the picture. Annoyingly I see the 3 commands as seen in the picture. I have used `sparklyr` and `dplyr` packages and in the script created Spark a connection using `sc <- spark_connect(master='local')` and then later closed using `spark_disconnect(sc)` command.

I want to close this panel in the `RStudio`. Appreciate any inputs.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2NMS.jpg]

Comment: It shows you as not connected - do you mean you just want to hide the panel? You can do that from Tools -> Global Options -> Pane Layout and uncheck Connections

Comment: @Calum You. No. I don't want to close the Connections tab. But I want those 3 lines appearing in that window to disappear. I also want to understand why those 3 lines are actually showing up.. Thanks.

Comment: If you delete them manually by the trash icon, it shows a message: "Are you sure you want to remove this connection form the connection history". So, I think is just a log.

Comment: @Colibri.... For some reason earlier the trash icon was not helping to remove the items... But I retried after your comment. Now It did work. May be my Rstudio had some update issue. Thank you.